# How to use find() method in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have to translate the .m file to simulink but I don't have any idea about How to use find() method. The result of the find() method is variable vector, which is not allowed by the simulink. Does anybody can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [matlab function block](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f6-106261.html) (or maybe a [prelookup](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/prelookup.html) might work, depending on the application).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[index]=find(data,1)
```

The second parameter of `find` specifies how many indices you want to find. Now `find` outputs a constant length vector and can be used in simulink.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this with the [Submatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dsp/ref/submatrix.html) or [Selector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/selector.html) blocks. This [answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38941) may be helpful.